# Why is Google indexing our robots.txt file and showing it in search results?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt

For some reason, Google is indexing the robots.txt file for some of our sites and showing it in search results.  See screenshots below.

Our robots.txt file is not linked from anywhere on the site and contains just the following:

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 5
```

This only happens for some sites.  Why is this happening and how do we stop it?

[image]

Screenshot 1: Google Search console

[image]

Screenshot 2: Google search results

Comment: According to your screenshot you use `robots.tx` instead of `robots.txt`. I don't know how google found that file, but as it is not the default name for the robots file, it might not automatically exclude it form search result?

Comment: The file name didn't fit on mobile.  Nice try. 

Comment: Well ignore my comment then …